# Qooxdoo Tooltip not working on Menu Button

Tags: qooxdoo

I can't seem to get a tooltip to stick to a menu button. Is this a bug?

```
  var menu = new qx.ui.menu.Menu();

  var undoButton = new qx.ui.menu.Button("Undo", "icon/16/actions/edit-undo.png", this.__undoCommand);

  var tooltip = new qx.ui.tooltip.ToolTip("test", null);
  undoButton.setToolTip(tooltip);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, qx.ui.menu.Button hides tool tips. Try

```
undoButton.setBlockToolTip(false);
```